# cherry framework wordpress where are the shortcodes?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm customizing a site built using cherry framework for Wordpress...
My "issue" is regarding a shortcode that generates a list of the recent posts of a x category... this is a built-in thingy in the theme...

What I need to to change the behaviour of the featured image... on click, I dont want the prettyphoto lightbox, I need the link to the post to be there instead...

I found right code to edit for the default Portfolio-book, but not for the shortcode.. i cant get the right piece of code...

the name of the shortcode that generates the gallery is:

**posts_grid columns**

and the code I'm implementing:

```
[posts_grid columns="3" order_by="date" order="DESC" thumb_width="333px" thumb_height="333px" meta="yes" link="yes" link_text="Leer más" category="masters" custom_class="masteres-list"]
```

I have searched the whole PHP documents but cannot seem to find the right piece of code that makes this happen...

I expect somebody who knows the framework to give some light on it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cherryframework.com/forums/topic/customizing-posts_grid/

Found the answer directly from the developer...